# How to take text area values and store it in hash map and sort?

Tags: java, hashmap, textarea

Here i'm taking input values from string and sorting,everything is working fine.but i need to take values from text area and store in hash map and sort.how to do that?
here is my code`<%
            out.println("<input type='textarea'>");
            String initial = "netbeans,eclipse,maven,ant,notepad,gedit";
            //HashMap<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            HashMap<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            result.put(2, "maven");
            result.put(0, "netbeans");
            result.put(1, "eclipse");
            result.put(4, "notepad");
            result.put(3, "ant");
            result.put(5, "gedit");
            Map<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(result);
            out.println(treeMap);
        %>` 
This is my demo.jsp page.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have will be run at the server (server-side code), however when a user enters some code into a browser input text area, then this will be happening on the client after the server code has rendered.

You could try using javascript or jquery to help you achieve what you want